# Modify default options in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I would like to change some default QGIS options.
For example, the default font used by QGIS composer on my system is ubuntu. I would like to change that.

I would also like to get no border when creating an object. 
Is there a config file I can create or modify in my .qgis user folder?

A user option file (like in scite editor) for example, would be valuable if it does not exists yet.

Comment: I think these are candidates for a feature request.

Comment: haven't seen that http://hub.qgis.org/issues/. Should maybe have a closer look

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. I think these are candidates for NEW feature requests.

Comment: will do that and maybe take to time to see how it can be done!

Comment: The [issue](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5216) is created. It has been tagged for v2

Comment: i'll close this since it ended up as a feature request